# When does a sub shell inherits its parent shell env?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Under what circumstances is the environment of the shell passed to the sub-shell?

Answer (score 5):

A subshell always gets all variables from the parent shell.

`man bash` will describe all the circumstances in which a subshell is used, which are mainly:
`command &`
`command | command` and
`( command )`

The so called environment only includes environment variables (`export variable`), and is passed on to every sub-process. Even when invoking `bash -c command`, which is not a sub-shell but a completely new bash instance.

In both cases changed values are not passed back to the parent process.