# Find references to files, recursively

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find, zsh

In a project where XML/JS/Java files can contain references to other such files, I'd like to be able to have a quick overview of what has to be carefully checked, when one file has been updated.

So, it means I need to eventually have a look at all files referencing the modified one, and all files referencing files which refer to the modified one, etc. (recursively on matched files).

For one level, it's quite simple:

```
grep -E -l -o --include=*.{xml,js,java} -r "$FILE" . | xargs -n 1 basename
```

But how can I automate that to match (grand-(grand-))parents?

And how can that be, maybe, made more readable?  For example, with a tree structure?

For example, if the file that interests me is called `modified.js`...

```
show-referring-files-to modified.js
```

... I could wish such an output:

```
some-file-with-ref-to-modified.xml
|__ a-file-referring-to-some-file-with-ref-to-modified.js
another-one-with-ref-to-modified.xml
|__ a-file-referring-to-another-one-with-ref-to-modified.js
    |__ a-grand-parent-file-having-ref-to-ref-file.xml
|__ another-file-referring-to-another-one-with-ref-to-modified.js
```

or any other output (even flat) which allows for quickly checking which files are potentially impacted by a change.

UPDATE -- Results of current proposed answer:

```
ahmsff.js
|__ahmsff.xml
|  |__ahmsd.js
|  |  |__ahmsd.xml
|  |  |  |__ahmst.xml
|  |  |  |  |__BESH.java
|  |__ahru.js
|  |  |__ahru.xml
|  |  |  |__ahrut.xml
|  |  |  |  |__ashrba.js
|  |  |  |  |  |__ashrba.xml
|  |  |  |  |  |  |__STR.java
|  |  |__ahrufrp.xml
|  |  |  |__ahru.js
|  |  |  |  |__ahru.xml
|  |  |  |  |  |__ahrut.xml
|  |  |  |  |  |  |__ashrba.js
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |__ashrba.xml
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |__STR.java
|  |  |  |  |__ahrufrp.xml
|  |  |  |  |  |__ahru.js
|  |  |  |  |  |  |__ahru.xml
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |__ahrut.xml
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |__ashrba.js
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |__ashrba.xml
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |__STR.java
|  |  |  |  |  |  |__ahrufrp.xml
(...)
```

Comment: Try Googling *"dependency graph"* plus the language of your choice, e.g. *"dependency graph python"* - maybe.

Comment: You have a design problem if file A affects file C that doesn't refer to A directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a shell function (for the recursion) inside an shell script:

Assuming the filenames are unique have no characters that need escaping in them:

File: `/usr/local/bin/show-referring-files-to`

```
#!/bin/sh

get_references() {
    grep -F -l --include=*.{xml,js,java} -r "$1" . | grep -v "$3" | while read -r subfile; do
        #read each line of the grep result into the variable subfile
        subfile="$(basename "$subfile")"
        echo "$2""$subfile"
        get_references "$subfile" '   '"$2" "$3"'\|'"$subfile"
    done
}

while test $# -gt 0; do
    #loop so more than one file can be given as argument to this script
    echo "$1"
    get_references "$1" '|__' "$1"
    shift
done
```

There still are lots of performance enhancements possible.

**Edit**: Added $3 to prevent infinite-loop.

Comment: Quite nice, and almost it!!!  There is just a problem: the fact that it loops (with file `ahrufrp.xml`). See example output in my edited question. Can you bring a solution to that?  Thanks!

Comment: Would you see a way to easily ignore files which have already been looked up in other parts of the tree, I'd be interested. As of now, on some real case examples, there is a lot of duplication between subtrees -- but no infloop anymore!

Comment: @user3341592 you could keep all files in a tempfile `tempfilename="$(tempfile)"`, and in the function add to `echo "$1" >> "$tempfilename"` and grep from  `grep -v -F -f "$tempfilename"` that file instead of using `$3`

Comment: For my own understanding, how would you try to optimize this, if this was needed?

Comment: From the top of my head, most speed gets lost on 2 things: file opperations (`grep -r`) and initializing a [subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41342512/5092659) which is a new process. Right now for each match both are done. It would be faster only doing this once per "level", e.g. remember second level matches and search for all 3rd level matches at one. Also gnu-parallel could be used. And if I would think about it more and perform some speed test, more and more would come up. Maybe collecting all (possible) filename-references first to reduce it to a single `grep -r`.

Comment: @user3341592 That is if you meant speed optimization. Otherwise fist priority should be a better matching grep: right now file `bar.js` finds references to `foobar.js`. And there are issues with quotable characters "Filename with \" inside.ext".

Comment: Thanks for all your tips and ideas!